# Flexible and Non frustrating parameter passing for Request processing system

Tags: c++

**Preface** This is a problem that I have run into surprisingly frequently and I must admit that there are many ways to solve it that I can think of, all the way from using a variadic function (bye bye type safety), to using a Hash Map (more type issues and feels like overkill) or just condemning users of my class to repetitive menial tasks for getting my system to work.
I am turning to this community to try and find a good way to do this, that doesn't hurt my soul.

**The Problem**
I will use a request processor as an example of this paradigm, you can easily see how the same may apply to other non request processing systems or slight mutations of request processing systems.

Say I have a Request Processor that looks somewhat like this :

http://pastebin.com/XriGa8U3

There are multiple instances of this Request Processor (for reasons) and each of them, as the comments point out, can have their own *defaultSerializedConfiguration*.

The method

```
unsigned int ProcessRequest(const float nonSerializedRequestConfigParam,const RequestConfiguration* requestConfig = 0);
```

However accepts a "RequestConfiguration*" parameter in case a particular request needs some slightly tweaked params, in general however, most instances of the request processor just use "defaultSerializedConfiguration".

Whenever tweaked requests are to be sent though, generally only one or two of the params are tweaked. The rest are to be the same as the "defaultSerializedConfiguration" values. Herein, comes the problem, now whenever someone is to send a tweaked request, they need to construct a valid "RequestConfiguration*" and fill in **all** the values.
All is the key word there, because, from the perspective of someone using this class, every time I want to change even one request processing param, I need to first get all of the default params then copy over the values that I am not changing "as is" then proceed to edit the one param that I do want to edit and finally call this method.

---

***Sidenote:*** This problem is compounded in the actual system that I have contrived into this example. There is no easy way to get the "defaultSerializedConfiguration" for this RequestProcessor. (How do you even interact with the thing to call the Process() method you ask ? Its done using a messaging system and there are complexities involved that would add more irrelevant fluff to this question)

---

So now, I am left with this annoying API that would be very frustrating and assbackwards from a user perspective.
i.e. The thing knows its default values, I really don't want to care about what they are, I just know that I want to mess with this one value, but every time I want to mess with one value, I must get the others and then muck with those too, just so I can get a call through.

**Solutions Considered**

The simplest solution is simply to break open "RequestConfiguration" and change the function signature of ProcessRequest to explicitly accept pointers to individual config params, something that looks like :

```
unsigned int ProcessRequest(const float nonSerializedRequestConfigParam, 
        const float* requestParam1 = 0, const std::string* requestParam2 = 0, const unsigned int* requestParam3 = 0);
```

I take multiple issues with this, ugly ass long function signature aside, the signature is also not very conducive to the request Params changing, every time a new requestParam is added it must be added into this function signature and the villagers will come at me with pitchforks.

Another solution may be to use a variadic function.
I personally just dislike them because of type safety concerns and they still don't solve the problem fully without having a really weird and complex call.
For example, if I say that the arg[0] will be requestParam1 , arg[1] will be requestParam2 and so on. Every time I want to mess with requestParam3, I will still have to fill in arg[0] , arg[1] and arg[2], thus leading back to the same issue. OR provide a format and once again have a shitty way for people to interact with my system (i.e. knowing weird formats to just make a request and pass a few params)

Finally, one can use a HashedMap , where the Key and the Value are both strings and depending on whatever entries were made into the map one can loop over it convert the Value from String to the requisite type. Since using the Key we will know what kind of value is contained in this record.

This method at face value seems ok, but the fact that one has to resort to constructing a hash map every time they make a request to my system seems kinda stupid. Then there is the cost incurred for creating a map, passing it around this can be done by reference since the ProcessRequest method works synchronously and once again the ugly api problem of having to create a map for something that should be, in essence simple as hell.
Also, if you think about it, this method is, in essence the same as a variadic function. Its just that the format is no longer one string but multiple strings describe the data coming in.

**Disclaimer**

I realize that this question is a perhaps a bit too long and drawn out for the stackoverflow tastes, but I trust the community of people here to know atleast one non soul crushing way to do this.

Also, the example code for the request processor is highly contrived, you may be tempted to ask questions like "Why do you need multiple instances of a request processor ?" It looks essentially stateless so you should probably just configure every request that comes in"

Trust me I would do things like that if I could, but I cant, the code is deeply embedded. It is not even really a request processing system and does have some state info that is independent of the "requestConfigurationParams"
So yeah, architectural changes are a no go.

Finally, the name of this question is stupid, but I couldn't think of a better one anyone who can think of a better one should definitely suggest the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a

```
const RequestConfiguration& GetDefaultConfiguration() const
```

So user can create easily a configuration from existing configuration. (look at [Prototype_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern))

Comment: I could and that would definitely work, the only issue is that the RequestConfiguration method would have to return a non const ref that would then have to be copied and then the user on the other side would have to have non const access to all data inside the 'RequestConfiguration' object , no real way to enforce the fact that the object making the requests is only allowed to tweak certain parameters.

Comment: In any case, it seems that there is no real good way of doing this other than the way you suggested and compromising a bit on the caller safety side.